# Aligment of images in leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

for some reason I don't manage to display 3 small images next to each other in 1 line. They are aligned vertically.

[image]

Code is like this:

```
var customOptions =
{
'maxWidth': '600',
'width': '400',
'className' : 'popupCustom'
}

var customPopup = "<b>Center</b>Test<br><br><div><center><a href=pinlisting.php?hideid=><img src=images/hide.png height=15.5 width=18></a><a href=delete2.php?delete&pin_db_id=1><img src=images/delete.png height=15.5 width=18></a><a href=index.php><img src=images/zoom.png height=15.5 width=18></a></center></div>";

L.marker(["coordinates"], {icon: "myIcon"}).addTo("myLayer").bindPopup(customPopup,customOptions);
```

Seems like some css problem but no clue

Comment: Can you post your css? What styles are currently being applied? It's extremely difficult to diagnose without more context and without styles.

Comment: Do you know how to inspect elements? How to use the browser's dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demo purposes I made your code more static:  I used HTML and CSS with flexbox, which can easily be converted to be generated by some JS:

```
  <div class="map">
    <h3>Map with Tooltip</h3>
    <div class="tooltip">
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="desc">Description</div>
      <div class="icons">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon icon-eye"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon icon-trash"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="icon icon-zoom"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The tooltip is a flex column positioned absolutely at a random position in my fake map:

```
.tooltip {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background:#ccc;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  position:absolute; top:20%; left:56%;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow:0 0.25em 1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

The bottom arrow of the tooltip:

```
.arrow {
  display:block;
  background:transparent;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-25px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-15px;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top:30px solid #ccc;
}
```

The `CENTER` element is EXTREMELY deprecated, and there is really no reason to use it anymore, we have lost of powerful new positioning and layout tools in CSS now, so `.icons` container is a flex box row:

```
.icons {
  flex:1 0 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  align-items:stretch;
  align-content:center;
}
```

Each icon link shares this CSS rule:

```
.icons a {
  flex:1 1 20px;
  border-radius:0.25em;
  background:white;
  box-shadow:0 0.125em 0.125em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  padding:0.25em 0.125em;
  margin:1px;
  width:1em; height:1em;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:1;
}
```

You will want to override the default link style for the icons:

```
a, .icon {
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

And I created some random icons from HTML entities:

```
.icon-eye:before {
  content:"\0260E";
}
.icon-trash:before {
  content:"\02605";
}
.icon-zoom:before {
  content:"\02665";
}
```

This entity chart is SUPER handy: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

I also created a `:hover` state for the icons:

```
.icons a:hover {
  box-shadow:0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.125);
}
```

My JSBin: http://jsbin.com/saxivi/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Based on the vertical stack, it seems that your `<a>` style was overwritten with `display: block;`. You could give each `<a>` specific class name then give them `display: inline-block` to make them horizontally stacked.

First, give specific class to `<a>`:

`var customPopup = "<b>Center</b>Test<br><br><div><center>
<a class='popupMarker' href=pinlisting.php?hideid=><img src=images/hide.png height=15.5 width=18></a>
<a class='popupMarker' href=delete2.php?delete&pin_db_id=1><img src=images/delete.png height=15.5 width=18></a>
<a class='popupMarker' href=index.php><img src=images/zoom.png height=15.5 width=18></a></center></div>";`

Then add css style somewhere:

```
.popupCustom .popupMarker {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the following class in your style sheet and use in your code.

```
.img-container {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

It worked for me when i had a similar problem.

Change your code to this:

```
var customPopup = "<b>Center</b>Test<br><br><div><center><a href=pinlisting.php?hideid=><div class="img-container"><img src=images/hide.png height=15.5 width=18></div></a><a href=delete2.php?delete&pin_db_id=1><div class="img-container"><img src=images/delete.png height=15.5 width=18></div></a><a href=index.php><div class="img-container"><img src=images/zoom.png height=15.5 width=18></div>
```